# apt-update returns strange error

Tags: apt, dpkg

am on kali linux and when I run `apt-get update` it returns this:

```
W: Unknown flag value:  yes
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

after running `apt-get update` several times it's still the same issue

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about system administration, not about programming. Furthermore it has been [reposted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154986/apt-get-returns-strange-error) on [unix.se] (where it is on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There is an error with one of the repositories.

Open /etc/apt/sources.list with your favourite txteditor, and put a # in front of deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main.